# How to pass List<Object> objects to a constructor parameter (Object object1, Object object2)?

Tags: java

My goal is to pass `List<Object> objects` to a constructor parameter `Object object1, Object object2`.

For example,

```
public class A {
  public A(Object object1, Object object2) {
  }
}
```

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    objects.add(new Object());
    objects.add(new Object())
    A a = new A(...objects);
  }
}
```

My expected result: It should work.

My actual result: The IDE throws error unexpected token.

Comment: For which parameter (`object1` or `object2`) do you want to send the object referenced by the `objects` variable and what value should the other parameter have?

Comment: What makes you think you should be able to pass `List<Object>` when two separate `Object` instances are required? `List` has no `put` method btw

Comment: What error do you get from your IDE?

Comment: @Eritrean I am going to use it dynamically e.g with `Class.class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance();`, so I can't do `objects.get(0)` because sometimes the parameter would be 1, then it would be 2, and so on.

Comment: @tgdavies it throws `unexpeted token` because I tried to do `...objects`.

Comment: @g00se i am just tinkering right now on how to initialize object dynamically that needs parameters to construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java, the language, has zero syntactical support for what you are trying to do here. And most likely never will, it is fundamentally tricky to do in java.

In general if you have a java method that takes a heap of arguments, all of which are of the same type, that's a badly designed method and you shouldn't be having it. Java could hypothetically grow a language feature that helps you out, but why cater to idiotic API designs, right?

Alternatively, you could have a `List<Object>` with a heterogenous (bunch of differently typed) objects, but you shouldn't have that either, it's un-java-like. Same cause for why java doesn't have this and probably never will: Why cater to bad code style?

Note that in java you can have 15 methods all with the same name differentiated solely by their types, so figuring out which one you actually intended to call is not necessarily simple.

You CAN do what you want with generics but it's a ton of code and very ugly:

```
public class Example {
    public void callMe(String a, Integer b) {}

    public void dynamicallyCallMe(List<Object> list) {
      Method m = Example.class.getMethod("callMe", String.class, Integer.class);
      m.invoke(this, list.toArray());
    }
}
```

You do not want to this.

If you're facing a scenario where you do want this, then you'd want to change the environment some. For example, if these arguments are being provided by a user via a config script or whatnot, the method you are calling should be aware of this, and should therefore follow the interface `public interface ConfigurableApp { void configure(List<String> aguments); }` or whatnot. Make it explicit. Write a wrapper if you must, which would then be the place in your code where you perform any translations as needed.

If you're facing a more code-heavy config concept (where the config file needs to contain code, or code-esque constructions), then go all the way and make it a script file, run it with a script runner. Let them write that config file in javascript or what not and execute it from your java process.

And so on.

---

EDIT: With some more insights provided via the comments on this question:

What you're likely looking for is an SPI system that discovers factories.

### SPI

SPI, or Service Provider Interface, is the name generally used in the java community for the idea of 'I have a mechanism by which a JDK can read a list of classes that implement some service straight from the classpath, usually via a file in `META-INF/services/fully.qualified.name.ServiceInterface` which lists 1 fully qualified classname per line. Reading these files out is baked into the core: [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). Making them - lots of utilities around that let you just annotate a class and an annotation processor makes the services file for you.

The java module system has its own take on this idea, using the `provides` keyword. I suggest you don't mess with the java module system, though. Nobody* uses it.

### Factories

The way `ServiceLoader` forces you to work, but this way is quite sensible so you should do this too (handrolling your own ServiceLoader is a single page class, so if you want to deviate, you can - it won't be difficult, it's just a bad idea stylewise), is that the involved classes have the following rules:

- They MUST implement/extend the service interface.
- They MUST have a public no-argument constructor.

The SPI system will then instantiate the class once using that constructor and will then give you a list of the service interface.

If this 'no arguments' thing is bothering you, that's when you add in a single layer of abstraction: The 'service' describes a factory, the classes in the META-INF/services class file are implementations of the factory service, and the factory's job is to make the instances you actually want.

### Example

Let's say we are an image editor and you want a pluggable 'find interesting objects using AI'.

You start by making an interface that describes an image filter:

```
public interface ThingieFinder {
    /** Describe what this thingiefinder finds */
    String getDescription();

    /** Try to find stuff within a segment of the image */
    List<Thingie> find(Coords coords, double howSeriously);
}
```

But what's missing in this description is the constructor which would, of course, take the object representing the entire image.

Factories are the answer. Make this interface too:

```
public interface ThingieFinderFactory {
    public ThingieFinder make(Image image);
}
```

This interface 'represents' the constructor. An implementation of this factory can be a trivial one-liner:

```
public class FaceFinderFactory implements ThingieFinderFactory {
    public FaceFinder make(Image image) {
        return new FaceFinder(image);
    }
}
```

and **this** factory has a single no-args public constructor! ThingieFinderFactory can be the service, and this can be an implementation of it.

*) Rounding down considerably, but it's *far* less than half and that doesn't appear to be changing.

Comment: I am learning to create a dependency injection framework. I tried to use `toArray()` and it works e.g. `HelloController.class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(parameters.toArray())`, is it generic, and is it bad?

Comment: yes, don't do that. If you want an abstracted ability to make an instance of a given class, do not have an API where the caller passes arguments and you go on the hunt for a constructor that 'fits'. Make a Factory class (a Factory abstracts the concept of constructors).

Comment: I checked Factory class and it intiliaze object with the `new` keyword, which means I need to know the constructor. For dependency injection framework, I think it is the only way I know right now to initialize an object from a List<Class>. List<Class> is from the `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` then map with `Class.forName()`.

Comment: I do agree that `getConstructors()[0].newInstance()` is ugly, I would love to know how to create a dependency injection framework. Spring Framework is one of them, but I am having difficulty to look at the source code and finding how they `scan a package` then initialize object that have `@RestController` annotation

Comment: @kidfrom I've added a considerable bit to the answer to show you how to use the concept of SPI and factories to get there in a java-esque way.

Comment: In my opinion, the SPI is not good because it is not thread safe and i have a limited knowledge, i think it needs `java module`, I tried to re-create `CodecFactory` from the link you referenced, but it `ServiceLoader.load(CodecFactory.class)` does not find the clasess that implements CodecFactory e.g. `CodecFactoryImpl implements CodecFactory`.

Comment: Another argument for the SPI is not good because a fellow on SO said that using annotation processing essentially create new file for every build and in a big project this will take very long time (I have not tested it).

Comment: Regarding patterns, I only know Builder Pattern. I think Factory Pattern is the more readable way to simplify constructor args to a minimum.

Comment: Regarding whether to use SPI and or with the Factory pattern. I don't find using `Patterns` would be useful in my use case, building a dependency injection framework `scan package -> build objects that have specific annotation -> achieve loosly coupled architecture`. Do you want to have a Zoom meeting, I can demo it to you why I think `Class.class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance()` is the only way to do it (as per my knowledge), assuming the framework does not know the `Class` type, everything are `Class<?>`.

Comment: @kidfrom. SPI does not require 'module' and is not thread unsafe. You need to make that services file. An annotation processor does not (unless badly designed) massively slow down your build. You also don't need an AP to do this, it just saves on manually managing that services file. Just search the web for an SPI tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Mulitple problems in your code

List does not have put method. Learn about List from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Java does not support spread operator(...) like JavaScript. In Java (...) is used for varargs

One of many ways to handle your errors.

```
public A(Object ... args) {
}
 
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(new Object());
objects.add(new Object());
A a = new A(objects);
```